# debian:jessie container, apt-get update 100% CPU in PhotonOS host

Tags: docker, vmware-esxi, apt

In a Photon OS machine in VMware ESXi:

```
docker run debian:jessie apt-get update
```

The `apt-get update` process takes several hours to finish, using ~100% CPU. Even with an empty `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

With `debian:stretch` the `apt-get update` executes as expected.

What could be happening? Where to look for troubleshooting this?

Comment: why? debian 8 is dead... long time ago. upgrade to a supported software. As for now the Question is offtopic. Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.

Comment: Morbid curiosity. It's a weird behaviour. I would like to understand it and thought this was the best place to ask.

Comment: i think but im not sure, but unix and linux would be the place - here it must have some requirements to ask on this site, even i know the sitename may confuse - if you want to read [ask] [help/on-topic]